# Why does LEFT(Datetime,1) give me "J"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

So I'm writing a SQL query and it gives me an odd error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'J' to data type int

I narrowed it down to a `LEFT(ProjApprovelDate,1)`, which for some reason gives me a J.

ProjApprovelDate is a DateTime most of the time, there are a few instances where it is entered incorrectly and is an int instead. To find these I've used `(LEFT(ap.ApprovalDate,1) != 1 and LEFT(ap.ApprovalDate,1) != 2)`. It always begins with either a 1 or 2 when it's in the wrong format. The whole column (in the original table) is int format and shows up with most dates like `20170614`, but there are several that show up like `1170614` instead. I'm converting these into the correct format and inserting them all into a new table with this column as DateTime so that it correctly makes them into a date.

When reviewing to make sure that I got them all I found this interesting case where the ones that are already formatted correctly as DateTime give me a J.

So my question is why does taking the first `LEFT` character of a DateTime give a `J` for the output?

Comment: If you do that on timestamps from December you'll get a D. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implicit conversion is a string, so...

```
Select cast(getdate() as varchar(25))
      ,left(getdate(),1)
```

**Returns**

```
(No column name)      (No column name)
Jun 14 2017 10:28AM   J
```

Take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine

**Just for fun, try**

```
Select left(25,1)
```

Comment: And if you just change the "1" to "25", you can see that.

Comment: @JohnPasquet Agreed, I just wanted to illustrate the implicit conversion of a datetime to the complete value.

Comment: Understood... just adding that tidbit in.

Comment: I realized as I walked away after posting this question that `LEFT` was converting all the dates to Jun 14, 2017, so the leftmost char is always going to be a J.  I should have realized that sooner.

Comment: @Mike Happens to the best of us.  :)